# Ridiculous ads which are potentially unsafe

Tags: discussion, advertising, virus

Today, I went on Stack Overflow, as so often when I want to to browse and learn something new and have suddenly seen three places with ads, which I have not seen before.

I understand that running the servers for Stack Exchange, especially Stack Overflow, must be very expensive but I have to say that it is rather offensive to see something like this:

[image]

The ad is German (I live in Germany) and it says approximately "Please, troubleshoot your Windows errors" in a highly flashy fashion. We all know that those ads ask you to install ridiculous tools that often don't do anything but install potentially dangerous malware. I have to say it is sad that I have stumbled over something like this on Stack Overflow, a website full of experienced and and ambitious programmers that are fully aware what often lies behind these banners.

A question has been asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28263/add-voting-to-ads) about voting on ads, which I personally find a good idea. But shouldn't ads like the one on the picture above be simply blocked at all costs and never appear on high quality websites like those by Stack Exchange?

Comment: Check if you see them over `https`. If not, your router or ISP is injecting it. If you still see them, it's probably a malicious browser extension or some other malware.

Comment: Check the URL. Is it really stackoverflow.com and not some other domain? Many are trying to steal traffic from SO by using similar domains and copying the contents.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I sincerely hope it was SO, as it is one of my Bookmarks that I always use. I will have to check my computer for malware when I'm back at home then! Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That ad is not one served by us. We don't serve ads above the topbar, and we would never allow an ad that looked like that for all sorts of reasons.

Most likely, you've either picked up some malware which is inserting ads, or your ISP is inserting ads.

Comment: Or, some copycat site.

Comment: I haven't heard of any german ISP that does that, and I'm pretty sure that would actually be illegal. OP most likely caught some adware.

Comment: Well if that is true, then I have to check for malware. Even though I am very thorough about this, but I will check it in more detail!

Comment: @phil13131 Yes, this seems like malware, probably something picked up as part of some installation. I would definitely check your plugins and toolbars.