# Ads on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, advertising

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I disable a specific annoying ad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad)
>   [Rate the quality of the ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24643/rate-the-quality-of-the-ads)

How do I get over the urge to install an ad blocker when looking at the following image on Stack Overflow?

http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/case-of-the-mondays-careers.png

Is it likely that posting a comment on meta.stackoverflow would cause it to go away? Or spontaneously add support for down voting particular ads?

Comment: For "Case of the Mondays": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad For voting on ads: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24643/rate-the-quality-of-the-ads

Comment: If you notice it, it must be working.  From that perspective, I doubt complaining about it will help.

Comment: @tvanfosson: It's *not* working if you have to fight the urge to install an ad blocker every time it gets in your face!

Comment: @fretje -- it depends on what you mean by "working" -- for ads, that generally means getting noticed. I don't intend to mean that it's good, just that it appears to make you pay attention.  From an advertiser's perspective getting such complaints might actually be viewed as a positive thing.

Comment: @tvanfosson: From an advertiser's perspective, yes, from a site owner's perspective, not so much.

Comment: It sounds like you have a case of the Mondays!

Comment: @Ether: Even though I hate the ad, I couldn't help but LOL at your comment.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` install an ad blocker. Help rid the internet of annoying adverts.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a specific filter to your ad-blocker or page-styling extension that blocks that particular ad. Then, no worries - you can still see other ads on Stack Overflow, and you won't have to look at that ad.

Answer (score -1):

Get 200 rep.  No more annoying ads.

Comment: They still show up in the sidebar.

Comment: Even with extra rep, Ms. Monday will still show up - it's a sidebar ad, which we *all* get the pleasure of seeing.

Comment: @tvan But those aren't annoying.

Comment: @Jared I never notice side bar ads unless I am looking for them.

Comment: I don't notice either of _the other_ adds as well. Buty this one is "Looking at you"!