# What happens when we vote on advertisements?

Tags: support, advertising

We can vote on advertisements in Stack Overflow, but what happen when we vote on an advert?

[image: advertisement voting]

Comment: Do you get that on each advertisement? I don't get that in incognito mode with my browser.

Comment: Where did you see that? Do you ask to add such feature?

Comment: No I see that add in each question (after the title of question). I do not have any extension. And if I vote on ad and refresh the page then I get another ad. I can vote on the new ad too.

Comment: Just don't vote randomly! :)

Comment: Yes I vote on ad which I like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh my.. you [have been chosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149140/152859)!

In short, it's a new feature that is still under development where users will be able to rate advertisements. (Note: only Careers "internal" advertisements, it's part of the Careers project)

The votes are obviously stored and this will give the team and probably the advertisers powerful tools to see how they're doing.

Comment: thank you for this info.