# A suggestion to the 'voting in ads' beta feature

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Devs are [currently testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149140/179635) a new feature that will allow us to rate the quality of the ads, it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that many of the visitors interested in ads will first click them, and probably never come back to rate them; on the other side, the ones that dislike them will almost always take the time to rate them.

There are two solutions to prevent losing potential positive feedback from clickers:

1. ***Use** the current feedback* and when someone clicks on them, mark them as positive
2. ***Remove** the current feedback* and get the successfulness or failure of an ad using the click-rate
   instead of manual rating

Comment: I'm sure they've always been tracking click-through rates...

Comment: I think they're trying to measure the acceptability of ads, there, not the successfulness.

Comment: The icons could be similar to the voting for questions/answers so people would be confident to vote more often.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is in the pudding, or rather, the clicks. And we've always tracked those, and will continue to do so. But you might like an ad, but not have a need for the service, and it will be interesting to see what data we'll gather from the up votes. Plus the thumbs down would look rather lonely all by itself.